# Solving an Iterated Integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Given the iterated integral:

$$\int^{\sqrt{2}}_{-\sqrt{2}}\int^{\sqrt{2-x^2}}_{-\sqrt{2-x^2}}\int^{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{3/2}}dzdydx$$

Now, my question is, what are the two quadric surfaces that bound the region from above and below, and what are their equations? Also, how do I integrate this?

I need help integrating this. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

The volume involves a cone, a cylinder, and a sphere .  And integration is facilitated by transforming to spherical coordinates with $x=r\sin \theta \cos \phi$, $y=r\sin \theta \sin \phi$, $z=r\cos \theta $, and $dxdydz\to r^2\sin \theta drd\theta d\phi$.

Comment: I'm very confused. Can you help me step-by-step with this problem, if you don't mind?

Comment: Imagine first a sphere with radius $2$.  Then, imagine a cylinder of radius $\sqrt{2}$ aligned along the $z$-axis.  Finally, imagine a cone with tip a the origin with its side making a $45$ degree angle with the $z$-axis.

Comment: So the volume is in side the cylinder and between the cone and sphere.

Comment: So the region is bounded above by the sphere and below by the cone?

Comment: Yes.  Draw a 2-D picture with the sphere a circe, the cylinder just parallel lines, and the cone two lines each of which makes a 45 degree angle with the $z$-axis.

Comment: Okay. Now how do I find the equations of this?

Comment: They are embedded in the limits of integration

Comment: So for the circle is it: $x^2+y^2=2$?

Comment: The sphere has radius $2$.  Do you know the equation for a sphere?

Comment: Oh sorry. $x^2+y^2+z^2=2$

Comment: Yes!  Well done.  Now you're getting there.

Comment: Can you help me integrate this?

Comment: Are you familiar with spherical coordinates?

Comment: I have heard of them but I'm not that familiar. Would you mind adding to your solution on how to integrate this. I know that this may seem that I'm only looking for an answer, but it does help me learn when I can see each step. If you don't mind, can you please show me a solution to this?

Comment: That is quite tedious and better left for you to work through 1 step at a time.

Comment: Can you set it up for me?